# Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets doesn't work in certain cells with custom formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-workspace, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

## Custom Formula doesn't work on certain cells.

A little background, I am making a timezone sheet for a discord where someone input the time they wanted and checks who is and is not available at that time. I decided Conditional Formatting will be great for this. I used the custom formula - =IF(TIMEVALUE(na)>=N,1) - **"n"** being the *column*, **"a"** being the *row*, and **"N"** being the number of your *time* (formatted as a number).

---

Example:

> =IF(TIMEVALUE(F4)>=0.875,1)

---

This being interpreted as any cells in that range greater or equal than 9 pm is colored "red".

---

So now, the first few works but once I got to 'F11:K11', it suddenly did not work.
[image]

I just copy-pasted the previous formula that I implemented on the first ones. I just changed the **"N"** value. This is was especially strange so I deleted it then remade it. Unfortunately, still did not work. I am absolutely stumped.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IoLE-NX_hNGQmpUxN4VK7peO9OFLs7Dhan1eopSlg8U/edit?usp=sharing

this is the link so you can see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It was just me being dumb after all. It was apparently the "a" factor that I was wrong about since the time basically revolved around cell F4 when it should have been "F11" or "F12" whatever row it was.